# The method by(String) is undefined for the type Advice.OffsetMapping.Sort

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to create a sort object and trying to sort by "seatNo". But getting this error message.

Appreciate your quick help.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wrong imported class - probably during an auto import in IDE.

Instead of `Advice.OffsetMapping.Sort` from `net.bytebuddy.asm` package, you should use `Sort` from `org.springframework.data.domain` package. The method `findAll` from [`PagingAndSortingRepostiory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) requires `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` class.

To fix this, just change the import statement for `Sort` in your class file to:

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
```